# Converting IOS project that contains thirdparty frameworks resulting in compilation error

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, windows-phone-8.1, winobjc

I tried to convert MY IOS project that use CocoaPods and thrid party frameworks like Facebook sdk Fabric SDK etc, using WInObjc. When I try to run the project it is throwing error. When I try a simple hello world project it succeeds. Is complex projects with Cocoapods and thirdparty frameworks supported in WinObjc right now?

Screenshot in the below link.
https://ichathan.tinytake.com/sf/MjYwMTE5XzE1OTAxMjA

Answer (score 0):

CocoaPods isn't available for C#. Use Nuget instead.
WinObjC is only in a preview now. It's in version 0.1. Don't expect it to work properly at the moment.